# Let A be an m × n matrix, and b an m × 1 vector, both with integer entries.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, and $b$ an $m \times 1$ vector, both with integer entries.
If $Ax = b$ has a solution over $ \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z $ for every prime $p,$ is a real solution guaranteed?

I have no clue whatsoever.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding completely but if $x$ has entries over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, if you take an entry $x_i$, $x_i=k$ where $0,\dots, p-1$ are equivalence classes mod p. So,  $x_i=pj+k$ for some $j\in \mathbb{Z}\cup \{0\}$.So, $x_i$ is real.

Comment: There will be some reduction mod p if you take entries over Z/pZ for example if p=3 and some x_i=5 then basically x_i=2 but such a thing will not happen over the reals. Does this make any sense?